# How to generate new page on my website using PHP?

Tags: php

How can i create new page on my website using PHP? I need PHP-code, which can create a new page. For example, i've got index.php and i need to create index2.php w/ PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe explain a little more what you need.

Comment: by writing html  and php code !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like above answer you can use **fopen() and fwrite()** to build a new .php file, or you could try using **[file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)** which would also generate a new file if it doesn't exist.

```
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

Example

```
$filename = "index2.php";
$content = "<h1>hello world</h1>";
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fopen() to create a file, and fwrite to edit it, more info here :
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Answer (score 0):

Open Notepad (if your do not have any other softwares like Notepad++ or Dreamweaver for editing PHP code), write your code there, Save the text file with .php extension in the same directory where your index.php file is located.